# How to correctly format the decimals of a number

Tags: c#, format, numbers

I am trying to format the balance received from the Ethplorer API.

(https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API#get-top-token-holders)

From the API I receive an array of JSON objects with the address, the balance and the amount that address represents for the token

Example:

`{"address":"XXX","balance":100000000000000,"share":0.04},...`

In the website browser I see that the balance formats them to appear like this (using JS (I have checked the source code and I don't really know what it does))

- `100000000000000 => 100.000.000,00`
- `254107403768716 => 254.107.403,768716`
- `751685000000 => 751.685,00`
- `679447550000 => 679.447,55`

I need them to be formatted in C# in the same way

```cs
var balance = 100000000000000;

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", balance));
// Output: 100.000.000.000.000,00

Console.WriteLine(balance.ToString("###,###,###"));
// Output: 100.000.000.000.000

// Expected: 100.000.000,00
```

Comment: no. you declared `long`. How do you expect `100.000.000,00`? As minimum, you can get `100.000.000.000.000,00`

Answer (score 0):

you've declared `long`. How do you expect `100.000.000,00`? As minimum, you can get `100.000.000.000.000,00`

in my culture I get this

```
Console.WriteLine(100000000000000.ToString(""#,#.00""));
```

> 100,000,000,000,000.00

For French I get this

```
Console.WriteLine(100000000000000.ToString("#,#.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-Fr")));
```

> 100 000 000 000 000,00

For UK is **seem what you need**

```
Console.WriteLine(100000000000000.ToString("#,#.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-Uk")));
```

> 100,000,000,000,000.00

Lets try decimal

```
var bal = 100000000000000.33m;
Console.WriteLine(bal.ToString("#,#.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-Uk")));
```